# I am getting following error when i was trying run Angular 7 code on stackblitz from github repo

Tags: angular, angular7, stackblitz

I am getting the following error when running Angular 7 code on stackblitz from github repo:

> Error in /turbo_modules/@angular/compiler@7.0.1/bundles/compiler.umd.js (1098:21)

Comment: What is the address of your StackBlitz application?

Comment: Did my answer fix your problem? Or yous still have it?

Comment: Working fine now @Jo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem with this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/github/Kirkify/angular-rerendering-problem

Just add `import 'core-js/es7/reflect';` to the `polyfills.ts` file to fix it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It now shows `Can't find package: core-js` with a "Install package `core-js`" which doesn't do anything. Project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-52eljz?file=src%2Fpolyfills.ts